# ¿Cómo ordeno una matriz en orden descendente?

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda para crear un código para ordenar una matriz de manera descendente y lo que he hecho hasta ahora es este código:

```
col=int(input('Ingresar numero de columnas:'))
fil=int(input('Ingresar numero de filas:'))
A=[[0 for i in range (col)] for j in range (fil)]
B=[[0 for i in range (col)] for j in range (fil)]
C=[0 for j in range (fil)]
print ('Matriz a: ')
for i in range (fil):
    for j in range (col):
        A[i][j]=input('Ingresar valor de la matriz A: ')
        B[i][j]=A[i][j]
C[i]=sorted(B[i][j])
for i in range (fil):
    for j in range (col):
        print (C[i])
```

el problema es que imprime los datos de esta forma

> ```
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> 0
> ['1']
> ['1']
> ['1']
> ```

Answer (score 2):

El problema de base ese esto:

```
C[i]=sorted(B[i][j])
```

`B[i][j]` representa un único elemento dado por los índices `i`, `j`, los cuales tienen el último valor de los ciclos anteriores es decir `range(fil)`  y `range(col)`. Por ejemplo, en una matriz de `2 x 2`, lo que en definitiva estarías haciendo es:

```
C[1]=sorted(B[1][1])
```

Con lo cual, lo que terminas haciendo es modificar la lista `C` y agregar en la posición 1, una nueva lista (ya que `sorted` te retorna una lista) que corresponde a un único elemento de la fila 1, columna 1 de `B`. En definitiva terminas con algo como esto:

```
fil = 2
col = 2
B = [["1","1"], ["1","1"]]
C = [0 for j in range(fil)]
C[1]=sorted(B[1][1])
for i in range (fil):
    for j in range (col):
        print (C[i])

print(C)

0
0
['1']
['1']
[0, ['1']]
```

Pareciera que lo que buscas es ordenar una fila entera, y guardarla de forma separada en `C`. Entonces el problema se soluciona, extrayendo correctamente la fila deseada:

```
fil = 2
col = 2
B = [["2","3"], ["1","5"]]
C=[0 for j in range (fil)]
for i in range(fil):
  C[i]=sorted(B[i], reverse=True)
print(C)

[['3', '2'], ['5', '1']]
```

Importante: Ten en cuenta que estás trabajando con cadenas, no con numéricos, por lo tanto el orden será alfanumérico.

Answer (score 1):

en Python, tienes la función **sorted**, la cual tiene la siguiente syntaxis:

```
sorted(iterable, *, key=None, reverse=False)
```

para el caso, usaremos `reverse`

Ejemplo:

```
lista = [1,3,5,4,2,8]
lista_desc = sorted(lista,reverse=True)
print(lista)        #esta es la lista normal
print(lista_desc)   #esta es la lista ordenada descendentemente
```

espero te sirva